# T-SQL | String "Manipulation" and Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following scenario.

**SOURCE TABLE 1**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 
(
     Div varchar(10), 
     Dept varchar(10), 
     States varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Table1
   SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','CA,NV,TX'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div2','Dept2','MI,OH,IN'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div3','Dept2','NY,NJ,PA'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div4','Dept1',NULL
```

**SOURCE TABLE 2**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table2 
(
    Div varchar(10), 
    Dept varchar(10), 
    States varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Table2
   SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','CA'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','NV, TX'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','TX, CA'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','CA, NV'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div2','Dept2','MI, OH'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div2','Dept2','MI, IN'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div2','Dept2','OH'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Div3','Dept2','NY, NJ, PA'
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
CREATE TABLE #Table3 
(
    Div varchar(10), 
    Dept varchar(10), 
    States varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #Table3
SELECT 'Div1','Dept1','CA - (3), NV - (2), TX - (2)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Div2','Dept2','MI - (2), OH - (2), IN - (1)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Div3','Dept2','NY - (1), NJ - (1), PA - (1)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Div4','Dept1',NULL

SELECT * FROM #Table1
SELECT * FROM #Table2
SELECT * FROM #Table3

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
DROP TABLE #Table3
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9801f)

Goal: Based on `#Table1` and `#Table2`, join both table on `Div` and `Dept` fields and then aggregate the counts for distinct states in `States` field and create an output where you have `Div`, `Dept`, and `States` with unique count of each one of those states printed next to the state.

I am not sure how to achieve this. I am trying `LIKE` but can't quite figure out how to make it dynamic. I will continue trying to see if I can figure out. Thought I would post this question here and see if I can get some assist.

Thank you

UPDATE:

Desired Output

```
Div     Dept    States
Div1    Dept1   CA - (3), NV - (2), TX - (2)
Div2    Dept2   MI - (2), OH - (2), IN - (1)
Div3    Dept2   NY - (1), NJ - (1), PA - (1)
Div4    Dept1   NULL
```

Comment: Can you add what output you want to the question?

Comment: @ZoffDino The desired output is the dataset in `#Table3`

Comment: Added the output-output. Cheers!

Comment: Multiple values should not be stored in a single field, this will be much easier if normalized.

Comment: Unfortunately, requirement is requiring me to store multiple values in one field with a comma-delimiter. The values can vary from 0 state (e.g. NULL) to like X number of States (e.g. "CA,NV,MN,TX,OK").

Comment: I guess the State count is only based on what appear in `Table2`?

Comment: Yep! One thing I should have mentioned is the possibility of NO states. Let me update the OP.

Comment: the States column should definitely be normalized

Comment: As much as I would like to have the field normalized,  I have to work with what I have in the source. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your requirements are very nasty but as developers we have to work with what we've got. Here's a solution using Common Table Expression (CTE) extensively:

```
;WITH
    CTE1 AS
    (
        SELECT      Div, Dept,
                    REPLACE(States,' ','') + ',' AS States
        FROM        Table2
    ),
    CTE2 AS
    (
        SELECT      c1.Div, c1.Dept,
                    LEFT(c1.States,CHARINDEX(',', c1.States)-1)                 AS IndividualState,
                    RIGHT(c1.States,LEN(c1.States)-CHARINDEX(',', c1.States))   AS RemainingStates
        FROM        CTE1    c1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      c2.Div, c2.Dept,
                    LEFT(c2.RemainingStates,CHARINDEX(',', c2.RemainingStates)-1),
                    RIGHT(c2.RemainingStates,LEN(c2.RemainingStates) - CHARINDEX(',', c2.RemainingStates))
        FROM        CTE2    c2
        WHERE       LEN(c2.RemainingStates) > 0
    ),
    CTE3 AS
    (
        SELECT      Div, Dept,
                    IndividualState,
                    COUNT(*)            AS StateCount
        FROM        CTE2
        GROUP BY    Div, Dept, IndividualState
    ),
    CTE4 AS
    (
        SELECT      t1.Div, t1.Dept,
                    (
                        SELECT  c3.IndividualState + ' - (' + CONVERT(varchar(10),c3.StateCount) + '), ' 
                        FROM    CTE3 c3
                        WHERE   c3.Div = t1.Div AND c3.Dept = t1.Dept
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                    )       AS States
        FROM        Table1  t1
    )

SELECT  Div, Dept,
        LEFT(States, LEN(States) - 1) AS States
FROM    CTE4
```

#### Explanation

1. `CTE1` cleans up the data in `Table2`: remove spaces, add a comma to the end
2. `CTE2` does the normalization
3. `CTE3` does the counting
4. `CTE4` does the final assembly, putting `CA | 3` into `CA - (3), ...`

The last `SELECT` remove the trailing comma for neater output.

To better understand each step, you can replace the final `SELECT` with `SELECT * FROM CTE1`, `SELECT * FROM CTE2`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so first of all, you'll need to split the concatenated values in `#Temp1` and `#Temp2`. There are various methods for doing so, I'll use the **numbers table** one that is described [in this awesome blog](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) post from Aaron Bertrand. So, we'll need a numbers table, which can be done this way:

```
;WITH n AS
(
    SELECT  x = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
)
SELECT Number = x
INTO #Numbers
FROM n
WHERE x BETWEEN 1 AND 8000;
```

Then, you'll need to actually do the splitting and then a group concatenation method for your result:

```
;WITH T1 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #Table1 T
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(T.States, Number,
                                         CHARINDEX(',',T.States + ',', Number) - 
                                         Number)
                 FROM #Numbers
                 WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(T.States))
                 AND SUBSTRING(',' + T.States, Number, LEN(',')) = ',') N
), T2 AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM #Table2 T
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(T.States, Number,
                                         CHARINDEX(', ',T.States + ', ', Number) - 
                                         Number)
                 FROM #Numbers
                 WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(T.States))
                 AND SUBSTRING(', ' + T.States, Number, LEN(', ')) = ', ') N
), T3 AS
(
    SELECT T1.Div, T1.Dept, T1.Item, COUNT(*) N
    FROM T1 
    LEFT JOIN T2
        ON T1.Div = T2.Div
        AND T1.Dept = T2.Dept
        AND T1.Item = T2.Item
    GROUP BY T1.Div, T1.Dept, T1.Item
)
SELECT  A.Div, 
        A.Dept, 
        States = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Item) + 
                                ' - (' + CAST(N AS VARCHAR(4)) + ')'
                        FROM T3 
                        WHERE Div = A.Div
                        AND Dept = A.Dept
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM T3 A
ORDER BY Div, Dept, Item
```

The results are:

```
╔══════╦═══════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ Div  ║ Dept  ║           States           ║
╠══════╬═══════╬════════════════════════════╣
║ Div1 ║ Dept1 ║ CA - (3),NV - (2),TX - (2) ║
║ Div1 ║ Dept1 ║ CA - (3),NV - (2),TX - (2) ║
║ Div1 ║ Dept1 ║ CA - (3),NV - (2),TX - (2) ║
║ Div2 ║ Dept2 ║ IN - (1),MI - (2),OH - (2) ║
║ Div2 ║ Dept2 ║ IN - (1),MI - (2),OH - (2) ║
║ Div2 ║ Dept2 ║ IN - (1),MI - (2),OH - (2) ║
║ Div3 ║ Dept2 ║ NJ - (1),NY - (1),PA - (1) ║
║ Div3 ║ Dept2 ║ NJ - (1),NY - (1),PA - (1) ║
║ Div3 ║ Dept2 ║ NJ - (1),NY - (1),PA - (1) ║
║ Div4 ║ Dept1 ║ NULL                       ║
╚══════╩═══════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally of course this data would be normalized, because this is messy.  Given that you're stuck with this structure, I think your best bet is to use a driver table of states or to use one of the many split functions available to split out the delimited values, and then use that, to get each state on it's own line:

```
;WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT b.Div,b.Dept,a.abbrs 
                FROM #States a
                RIGHT JOIN #Table1 b
                 ON ','+REPLACE(b.States,' ','')+',' LIKE '%,'+a.abbrs+',%'
              )
     ,cte2 AS (SELECT b.Div,b.Dept,a.abbrs 
                FROM #States a
                JOIN #Table2 b
                 ON ','+REPLACE(b.States,' ','')+',' LIKE '%,'+a.abbrs+',%'
              )
     ,cte3 AS (SELECT a.Div,a.Dept,a.abbrs,CAST(COUNT(b.abbrs)AS VARCHAR(25)) CT 
                FROM  cte a
                LEFT JOIN cte2 b
                 ON a.Dept = b.Dept
                 AND a.Div = b.Div
                 AND a.abbrs = b.abbrs
                GROUP BY a.div,a.dept,a.abbrs
              )
SELECT DISTINCT
      Div,Dept
      ,STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' +   abbrs+'-('+CT+')'
                                    FROM cte3 b                         
                                    WHERE a.Div = b.Div
                                      AND a.Dept = b.Dept
                                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
                                    ,1,1,'')

FROM  cte3 a
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c2264/1/0)

Note:

- cte1 - creates distinct list of div/dept/state from table1
- cte2 - creates list of all div/dept/states from table2
- cte3 - aggregates on div/dept/state to get the count

Output is:

```
|  DIV |  DEPT |               STATES |
|------|-------|----------------------|
| Div1 | Dept1 | CA-(3),NV-(2),TX-(2) |
| Div2 | Dept2 | IN-(1),MI-(2),OH-(2) |
| Div3 | Dept2 | NJ-(1),NY-(1),PA-(1) |
| Div4 | Dept1 |               (null) |
```

Updated fiddle to include your `NULL` line and added output.

Comment: Thanks @Goat CO for this awesome help. Really appreciate it. Cheers!